# Is it possible to use gem faker from my yml file?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

My great desire is to use the gem faker inside the yml file. I know this way is wrong, but is it possible to do it?

see my code:

------yml file -----

```
:usuarios:
  :ncpf:             Faker::Number.number
  :birth             Faker::Date.birthday
```

---my page (site-prism)-----

```
def new_user
    cpf.set(DADOS[:users][:ncpf])
    dt_birth.set(DADOS[:users][:birth])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, this is not possible with plain YAML. But when you run your YAML file through ERB before parsing then you can do that.

Change your YAML to

```
:users:
  :ncpf:   <%= Faker::Number.number %>
  :birth:  <%= Faker::Date.birthday %>
```

and read the file like this

```
require 'erb'
require 'json'

file = File.read('path/filename.yml')
yaml = ERB.new(file).result

DADOS = YAML.load(yaml)
```

Btw this is what Rails does internally with configuration files. So when you are using Rails then you can use this simplified version to load that file

```
DADOS = ActiveSupport::ConfigurationFile.parse('path/filename.yml')
```

Comment: spickermann, Thank you! It still didn't work, what's wrong here in my code? .. Please   file = File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/massa/tb.yml")
yaml = ERB.new(file).result
DADOS = YAML.load(File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/massa/tb.yml")))        My estructure: AUT_FRONT ---Features\support\massa\tb.yml

Comment: Your line starting with `DADOS =` looks different than the some in my answer. Your version basically doesn't use the `ERB` part and therefore ist cannot work.

Comment: what a shame!!.. Thank you